# Sphinx clean installation broken from the start

Tags: python-3.x, homebrew, python-sphinx

I installed [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/) with

```
   brew install sphinx
```

But when I call `sphinx-quickstart`, this is what happens:

```
cls ~/workspace/SphinxTest $ sphinx-quickstart 
-bash: /usr/local/share/python3/sphinx-quickstart: /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.2.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/Resou: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

My current `python3` is Python 3.3.0 at `/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.0`. I previously had also Python 3.2.3 installed but this got uninstalled during a homebrew cleanup. Why does homebrew still try to use the uninstalled version of Python 3? How can I get a working Sphinx?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've probably figured this out by now, but the `sphinx` package in `homebrew` isn't the Sphinx documentation generator linked to in the question. It actually refers to the open source search server [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/).

You're probably better off using [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/) or [easy_install](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html) to install the [Python Sphinx package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Sphinx):

```
pip install Sphinx
```